# 500 internal server error when ReST query executed from the SP host machine

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, rest

We have SharePoint 2010 hosted on Windows Server 2008 R2 server. We are trying to access the data in the SP lists using REST queries (`GET`) such as

```
http://server:port/sites/sitecollection/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/listname?$filter=ColumnName eq ‘Value’
```

This query works fine when we access it from any machine other than the server.
However, when we access it from the server that hosts SP, we get 500 internal server error.

Comment: You are missing a `t` in `lisdata.svc`, should be `listdata.svc`

Comment: Sorry for the typo. But with the correct query we are getting the error.

Comment: Also the `'`around `Value` looks off, is that to a typo?

Comment: Yes @RobertLindgren. As I said, if I make the query using the IE (11) on my machine (Win 7 Enterprise 64 bit) or any other machine it works fine and we get the response. But when we do it from the browser in the same machine (where SP is hosted), it fails. Other queries works fine though.

Answer (score 1):

If it works everywhere but on the server then you might be running into the "loop back check" issue. Spence Harbor has a very good post on this: [Link](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2009/07/02/disableloopbackcheck-amp-sharepoint-what-every-admin-and-developer-should-know.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

There is a typo (`‘` is not allowed) in your request, the fixed request:

```
http://server:port/sites/sitecollection/site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/listname?$filter=ColumnName eq 'Value'
```

### Troubleshooting REST

It is frequently useful to view the HTTP messages that are being sent and received, the following tooling could be utilized for that purpose:

- Debugging tools built into browser, such as [IE Developer Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)
- [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)

### References

[Common REST API Error Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179357.aspx)

Comment: I wish you had read the comments along with. The typos are when I editied it here. As I have said time and again, the same query, Verbatim I say again, works from a remote machine in the network. But if I login (mstsc!) to the server (where the SP is running) and run it there, it fails.

Comment: Have you ever tried to analyze the Http messages using the tools I have mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Yes @Vadim. I could not get any hint. I used Fiddler as well as the developer tool in the browser (both IE11 and FF). I have not used Wireshark though.